# Orchard Workflow and Comments - get the owner email of the content item the comment is attached to

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I have a content item called `Contracts` that has the comments part attached.

I am trying to use a workflow to send a user an email to let them know that their comment has been replied to by admin.
I want to send the user an email if admin has commented on their contract.

I have created a workflow that fires when a new comment is created.

However, in the `send an email` workflow item I can't find a token that represents the owner of the contract being commented on. `{User.Email}` only gets the email of the person making the comment, not the owner of the content item.

Any ideas would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the token I needed was `{Content.CommentedOn.Author}`